How to get the parameter from URL of a redirect url in jmeter
In my load test script i have one POST request which send the data to server as "multipart/form-data". After successful run of this request it automatically redirects to some other URL.

multipart/form-data post request didn't show any response body from where i can get the parameters for subsequent request.

i have tried multiple options:

post processor regular expression extractor(with Main sample and sub samples, Main sample only, Response Headers, Request Headers, URL)

In first request which redirect to other page i checked "Response Headers" and found No "Location:" property.
But when i run the same scenario in browser i noticed that ":path:" property is displaying under "Request Header" in the subsequent request

and JMeter is unable to capture these properties which are inbetween colons or i can say custom headers
could any body please help how to get the parameter from redirect URL?

Redirections doesn't provide any response body, they provide the target URL in Location header
So you need to setup your Regular Expression Extractor to something like:


Thanks for the reply, In first request which redirect to other page i checked "Response Headers" and no "Location:" property found. But when i run the same scenario in browser i noticed that ":path:" property is displaying under "Request Header" in the subsequent request and JMeter is unable to capture these properties which are inbetween colons or i can say custom headers. Updated the question for more visibility your help is highly appreciated.
